# Error 500 Server POST MultiPart Data WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need some help for posting a MultipartFormDataContentto my web service.
I have an error 500 but I didn't know why.

There is a mean to see what kind of data i send with visual studio? Or there is a mistake in my code?

My c# code Client

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            using (var content =
                new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {



                MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s);
                writer.Write(json);
                writer.Flush();
                s.Position = 0;
                content.Add(new StreamContent(s), "JSON");


                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, byte[]> pair in data)
                {

                    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(pair.Value);
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(stream),"uploaded");

                }

                using (
                   var message =
                       await client.PostAsync(urlFinal, content))
                {
                    var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                }
            }
        }
```

And the Web Service part in JAVA

```
   public static Result Method() {
    MultipartFormData data = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    return ok(toJson(MyObject.myMethode(data)));
}

    public static int myMethode(MultipartFormData data) {


    FilePart JSON = data.getFile("JSON");
    FilePart picture = data.getFile("uploaded");

    return 1; 
    }
```

Comment: you can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for network debugging.

Comment: I can't use it because i can't use it with my network policies